# session management with Flex+Java Servlet using Httpservice

Tags: apache-flex, servlets

I am new to Flex. I am just wondering how to manage session and cookies for logging in, logging off in Flex? 
I am using Flex HttpService and Java servlet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using Flex, you have the power of RIA that lets you apply the "Statelessness" REST is fighting for.  Just go stateless, and send the credentials on each request. Keep your session on the client side.